# If a 1lb magnet with a 100lb load was levitating; would the force pressing down be less than or equal to a 101lb weight that wasn't levitating?

Tags: magnetic-fields

My guess is that it would require the same amount of force to lift the same amount of weight regardless if levitating or not. That may be a seperate question.
I suppose this question could be associated with levitation by any form such as air pressure.

Answer (score 0):

If we imagine a free body diagram of this situation, we have gravity pointing down, with a force of $101$ lb, and the levitating force pointing up. The levitating force must be equal to $101$ lb for the net force to be zero (which is implicit in the fact that it is levitating).

After considering the free body diagram, we can see that even though the gravitational force is balanced-out, it is still very much there, pressing down on the $101$-lb system.

Comment: To a person who's never passed physics I think I can picture this. Thank you. It sounds to me that it would be equal regardless if levitating or not. It also sounds like it would also take the equal amount of force to lift the weight regardless if 100lb was levitating or not. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Almost. If it was levitating, it would take *no* force to lift it, since the net force on it would be zero. If it moved out of range of whatever field was holding it up, though, it would require a force to lift.

Comment: If the magnet with the 100lb weight remained in place & I was holding.the bottom magnet in my hand, are you saying that because the net force is 0 that i could lift this 100lb weight without it actually feeling like 100lb? Or the opposite? I'm sorry haha this is just very interesting & I want to get it right! Thanks!

Comment: Yes, but for how long depends on the properties of the field holding it up. In a case where the force depends on where the magnet is, then it will only feel weightless for the moment you begin moving it.